# Делегирование событий JavaScript. Как правильно удалить блок на странице по нажатию на кнопку?

Tags: javascript, события, dom

```js
const taskListBlock = document.querySelector('.task-list');
// const taskBlock = document.querySelector('.task');
let removeButton = document.querySelector('.task__removeButton');

function addTask() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('#taskText');
  const taskText = textarea.value;
  textarea.value = '';

  let taskListElement = document.createElement('li');
  taskListElement.className = 'task-list__element task';
  taskListElement.innerHTML = `
  <p>${taskText}</p>
  <div class="btn task__markImportantButton">
    MARK IMPORTANT
  </div>
  <div class="task__removeButton">
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M26.9844 11.9844V14H13.0156V11.9844H16.4844L17.5156 11H22.4844L23.5156 11.9844H26.9844ZM14 26.9844V14.9844H26V26.9844C26 27.5156 25.7969 27.9844 25.3906 28.3906C24.9844 28.7969 24.5156 29 23.9844 29H16.0156C15.4844 29 15.0156 28.7969 14.6094 28.3906C14.2031 27.9844 14 27.5156 14 26.9844Z"
        fill="#666666" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#C4C4C4" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  `;

  if (taskText != '') {
    taskListBlock.appendChild(taskListElement);
  }
}

removeButton.onclick = function (event) {

  let taskToDelete = event.target.closest('.task');

  if (!taskToDelete) return;

  taskListBlock.removeChild(taskToDelete);
}
```

```css
/* ? STYLE RESET */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0 20px;  
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

input,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

/* img {
  max-width: 100%;
} */

/* ? STYLES */

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1346px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper__aside {
  width: 760px;
}

.btn {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 218px;
  /* top: 6px; */
  right: 6px;
  width: 903px;
  height: 735px;
  background: url(../images/bg.svg);
}

/* ? header */

.header .wrapper__aside {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0 31px;
}

.logo {
  width: 174px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(../images/logo.svg);
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

.header__search {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-icon {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url(../images/search.svg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
}

.search-input {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 37px;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search::placeholder {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.3;
}

/* ? tabs */

.tabs .wrapper__aside {
  display: flex;
  border-top: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}

.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: rgba(5, 53, 101, 0.5);
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.tab.tab--active {
  border-top: 4px solid #2F80ED;
  color: #53565A;
}

/* ? add-task */

.add-task {
  padding-bottom: 23px;
}

.add-task .wrapper {
  padding: 18px 0 23px;
}

.add-task .wrapper__aside {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.add-task__heading {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #706E6B;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.add-task__textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDBDA;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-add {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 191px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2F80ED;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}

/* ? tasks */

.task-list__element {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.task {
  position: relative;
  width: 763px;
  height: 109px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* padding: 16px; */
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.task-list .task:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px rgba(29, 125, 232, 0.75);
  transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
}

.task p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 428px;
  height: 77px;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
}

.task:hover p {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}

.task-list__element:hover,
.task-list__element:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgba(47, 128, 237, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.task__markImportantButton,
.task__removeButton {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task-list__element:hover .task__markImportantButton,
.task-list__element:hover .task__removeButton {
  display: block;
}

.task__markImportantButton {
  width: 183px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(16, 177, 88, 0.8);
  top: 11px;
  right: 73px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.task__removeButton {
  top: 11px;
  right: 12px;
}

/* ! --------------- RESPONSIVE LAYOUT --------------- */

@media (max-width: 1024px) {}

@media (max-width: 768px) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
  <title>Todo app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </div>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper__aside">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="header__search">
          <div class="search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search task for to do">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="tabs">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="wrapper__aside">
          <li class="tab tab--active">All</li>
          <li class="tab">Active</li>
          <li class="tab">Done</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="add-task">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="wrapper__aside">
          <p class="add-task__heading">New Task</p>
          <textarea class="add-task__textarea" name="" id="taskText"></textarea>
          <div class="btn btn-add" onclick="addTask()">ADD</div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="tasks">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper-aside">
          <ul class="task-list">
            <li class="task-list__element task">
              <p>Попить чайку</p>
              <div class="btn task__markImportantButton">
                MARK IMPORTANT
              </div>
              <div class="task__removeButton">
                <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M26.9844 11.9844V14H13.0156V11.9844H16.4844L17.5156 11H22.4844L23.5156 11.9844H26.9844ZM14 26.9844V14.9844H26V26.9844C26 27.5156 25.7969 27.9844 25.3906 28.3906C24.9844 28.7969 24.5156 29 23.9844 29H16.0156C15.4844 29 15.0156 28.7969 14.6094 28.3906C14.2031 27.9844 14 27.5156 14 26.9844Z"
                    fill="#666666" />
                  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#C4C4C4" fill-opacity="0.5" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="task-list__element task">
              <p>Попить кофе</p>
              <div class="btn task__markImportantButton">
                MARK IMPORTANT
              </div>
              <div class="task__removeButton">
                <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M26.9844 11.9844V14H13.0156V11.9844H16.4844L17.5156 11H22.4844L23.5156 11.9844H26.9844ZM14 26.9844V14.9844H26V26.9844C26 27.5156 25.7969 27.9844 25.3906 28.3906C24.9844 28.7969 24.5156 29 23.9844 29H16.0156C15.4844 29 15.0156 28.7969 14.6094 28.3906C14.2031 27.9844 14 27.5156 14 26.9844Z"
                    fill="#666666" />
                  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#C4C4C4" fill-opacity="0.5" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </main>

  <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

По нажатию на кнопку я могу добавить новую задачу в список задач. Изначально на странице у меня уже добавлено 2 задачи. При нажатию на кнопку удалить у меня удаляется только первая задача, а вторая нет, в том числе не удаляются новые добавленные задачи, хотя они абсолютно идентичные по структуре html. Есть подозрение, что это происходит из-за того, что я получаю кнопку через метод querySelector(), а в MDN написано что этот метод всегда выбирает первый элемент по селектору (классу), поэтому и удаляется только первая задача. Но когда я использую getElementByID/ getElementByClassName вообще ничего не удаляется. Как исправить это?

Comment: `removeButton.forEach( (button) => { button.onclick =...; })`

Comment: @InDevX и следующим вопросом будет "не удаляются созданные задачи"

Comment: вообще теперь ничего не удаляется

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let removeButton = document.querySelector('.task__removeButton');
removeButton.onclick = function...
```

Вы здесь добавляете обработчик клика на первую кнопку. А идея делегирования в другом: Нужно добавить обработчик на ближайшего родителя, который наверняка всегда будет на странице. Обработчик должен определить, на кого кликнули и выполнить действие. В таком случае при добавлении / удалении новых элементов не придется отдельно думать про обработку событий для каждого из них.

Добавлен код после `***`:

```js
const taskListBlock = document.querySelector('.task-list');
// const taskBlock = document.querySelector('.task');

function addTask() {
  const textarea = document.querySelector('#taskText');
  const taskText = textarea.value;
  textarea.value = '';

  let taskListElement = document.createElement('li');
  taskListElement.className = 'task-list__element task';
  taskListElement.innerHTML = `
  <p>${taskText}</p>
  <div class="btn task__markImportantButton">
    MARK IMPORTANT
  </div>
  <div class="task__removeButton">
    <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path
        d="M26.9844 11.9844V14H13.0156V11.9844H16.4844L17.5156 11H22.4844L23.5156 11.9844H26.9844ZM14 26.9844V14.9844H26V26.9844C26 27.5156 25.7969 27.9844 25.3906 28.3906C24.9844 28.7969 24.5156 29 23.9844 29H16.0156C15.4844 29 15.0156 28.7969 14.6094 28.3906C14.2031 27.9844 14 27.5156 14 26.9844Z"
        fill="#666666" />
      <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#C4C4C4" fill-opacity="0.5" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  `;

  if (taskText != '') {
    taskListBlock.appendChild(taskListElement);
  }
}

/***/
taskListBlock.addEventListener('click', function(e) {  
  let del = e.target.closest('.task__removeButton');
  
  if (del) taskRemove(del);
  // Если возможных целей несколько, можно организовать через switch вместо if.
});

function taskRemove(btn) {
  let task = btn.closest('.task-list__element.task');
  taskListBlock.removeChild(task);
}
```

```css
/* ? STYLE RESET */

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  max-width: 100%;
}

body {
  padding: 0 20px;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
}

input,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
}

ul>li {
  list-style-type: none;
}


/* img {
  max-width: 100%;
} */


/* ? STYLES */

body {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 1346px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper__aside {
  width: 760px;
}

.btn {
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 218px;
  /* top: 6px; */
  right: 6px;
  width: 903px;
  height: 735px;
  background: url(../images/bg.svg);
}


/* ? header */

.header .wrapper__aside {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px 0 31px;
}

.logo {
  width: 174px;
  height: 44px;
  background: url(../images/logo.svg);
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: -24px;
}

.header__search {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
}

.search-icon {
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  background: url(../images/search.svg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 15px;
}

.search-input {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 37px;
  background: #F6F6F6;
  border: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
  box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.search::placeholder {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #000000;
  opacity: 0.3;
}


/* ? tabs */

.tabs .wrapper__aside {
  display: flex;
  border-top: 1px solid #E2E2E2;
}

.tab {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 175px;
  height: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 20px;
  color: rgba(5, 53, 101, 0.5);
  font-weight: 900;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.tab.tab--active {
  border-top: 4px solid #2F80ED;
  color: #53565A;
}


/* ? add-task */

.add-task {
  padding-bottom: 23px;
}

.add-task .wrapper {
  padding: 18px 0 23px;
}

.add-task .wrapper__aside {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.add-task__heading {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #706E6B;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
}

.add-task__textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 90px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  padding: 16px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDBDA;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.btn-add {
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 191px;
  height: 36px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2F80ED;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
}


/* ? tasks */

.task-list__element {
  margin-bottom: 17px;
}

.task {
  position: relative;
  width: 763px;
  height: 109px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  /* padding: 16px; */
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.task-list .task:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px rgba(29, 125, 232, 0.75);
  transition: all .05s ease-in-out;
}

.task p {
  position: absolute;
  width: 428px;
  height: 77px;
  top: 16px;
  left: 16px;
}

.task:hover p {
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
}

.task-list__element:hover,
.task-list__element:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgba(47, 128, 237, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 0px 6px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.task__markImportantButton,
.task__removeButton {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task-list__element:hover .task__markImportantButton,
.task-list__element:hover .task__removeButton {
  display: block;
}

.task__markImportantButton {
  width: 183px;
  height: 36px;
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(16, 177, 88, 0.8);
  top: 11px;
  right: 73px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}

.task__removeButton {
  top: 11px;
  right: 12px;
}


/* ! --------------- RESPONSIVE LAYOUT --------------- */

@media (max-width: 1024px) {}

@media (max-width: 768px) {}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
  <title>Todo app</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="bg"></div>
  </div>

  <header class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="wrapper__aside">
        <div class="logo"></div>
        <div class="header__search">
          <div class="search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></div>
          <input class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search task for to do">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

  <main>
    <section class="tabs">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <ul class="wrapper__aside">
          <li class="tab tab--active">All</li>
          <li class="tab">Active</li>
          <li class="tab">Done</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="add-task">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <form class="wrapper__aside">
          <p class="add-task__heading">New Task</p>
          <textarea class="add-task__textarea" name="" id="taskText"></textarea>
          <div class="btn btn-add" onclick="addTask()">ADD</div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="tasks">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="wrapper-aside">
          <ul class="task-list">
            <li class="task-list__element task">
              <p>Попить чайку</p>
              <div class="btn task__markImportantButton">
                MARK IMPORTANT
              </div>
              <div class="task__removeButton">
                <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M26.9844 11.9844V14H13.0156V11.9844H16.4844L17.5156 11H22.4844L23.5156 11.9844H26.9844ZM14 26.9844V14.9844H26V26.9844C26 27.5156 25.7969 27.9844 25.3906 28.3906C24.9844 28.7969 24.5156 29 23.9844 29H16.0156C15.4844 29 15.0156 28.7969 14.6094 28.3906C14.2031 27.9844 14 27.5156 14 26.9844Z"
                    fill="#666666" />
                  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#C4C4C4" fill-opacity="0.5" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </li>

            <li class="task-list__element task">
              <p>Попить кофе</p>
              <div class="btn task__markImportantButton">
                MARK IMPORTANT
              </div>
              <div class="task__removeButton">
                <svg width="40" height="40" viewBox="0 0 40 40" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                  <path
                    d="M26.9844 11.9844V14H13.0156V11.9844H16.4844L17.5156 11H22.4844L23.5156 11.9844H26.9844ZM14 26.9844V14.9844H26V26.9844C26 27.5156 25.7969 27.9844 25.3906 28.3906C24.9844 28.7969 24.5156 29 23.9844 29H16.0156C15.4844 29 15.0156 28.7969 14.6094 28.3906C14.2031 27.9844 14 27.5156 14 26.9844Z"
                    fill="#666666" />
                  <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" fill="#C4C4C4" fill-opacity="0.5" />
                </svg>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </main>

  <script src="./scripts/script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо тебе, добрый человек)

Answer (score 0):

let removeButton = document.querySelectoy('.task__removeButton')

В эту переменную записывается первый элемент, поэтому только первая задача и удаляется

Comment: да, я так и предположил. Но дело в том что с другими методами вообще не работает

Answer (score 0):

если на родителя повесить примерно так

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul class="tasks">
        <li><button class="but">1</button></li>
        <li><button class="but">2</button></li>
        <li><button class="but">3</button></li>
        <li><button class="but">4</button></li>
    </ul>
    <script>
        const tasks = document.querySelector('.tasks')

        tasks.addEventListener('click', event => {
            if (event.target.classList.contains('but')){
                console.log(event.target.innerText)
            }
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```